# Populate list before calling method Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating a social app and as soon as the user opens the app, they are suppose to see random posts that I load from the database.

But I don't see that and I have to click on the `Random` tab to see the posts. So my guess is that the list isn't populated with data by the time the method `readRandPosts();` gets called. It's not showing up as null so I have no clue what's wrong. I've checked multiple answers on here and still found nothing to solve my problem. Can someone please help me see what I'm doing wrong ?

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private PostAdapter postAdapter;
private List<Post> postLists;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();

    homeFragment.post = post;

    //////////////////////////// recycler view //////////////////////////////
    recyclerView = (VideoPlayerRecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    //layoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);
    layoutManager.setReverseLayout(false);
    layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(false);
    VerticalSpacingItemDecorator itemDecorator = new VerticalSpacingItemDecorator(0);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecorator);

    postLists = new ArrayList<>();
    //postLists.clear();
    postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(), postLists);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);

    progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_circular);

    followingBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.followingBtn);
    randomBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.randomBtn);

    followingBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            checkFollowing();

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Following", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    randomBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            readRandPosts();
            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Random", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    readRandPosts();

    if (postLists != null) {

        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "not null.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Posts are null.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return view;
}
```

---

```
private void readRandPosts() {

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Video_Posts");
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            postLists.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                assert post != null;

                if (user != null ) {

                    DatabaseReference dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Follow")
                            .child(post.getPublisher())
                            .child("followers")
                            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

                    dbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                                postLists.add(post);
                                //Collections.shuffle(postLists);
                            } else {
                                //postLists.add(post);
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Nothing to show.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        }
                    });

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "User null.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            if(postLists == null ) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            //Collections.reverse(postLists);

            postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not showing up as null because you are assigning a new ArrayList to the variable here:

`postLists = new ArrayList<>();`

So instead of checking for null, you should be checking if the list is empty.

Comment: So how do I populate it before I call it ?